# Android Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android

I am making an application, when I run that application I am getting following error during running.

```
[2015-06-19 17:11:06 - Ecommerce] Installation error:      
[2015-06-19 17:11:06 - Ecommerce] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2015-06-19 17:11:06 - Ecommerce] Launch canceled!
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong, I saw so many solutions but that does not match to my problem. Here is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ecommerce.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
       />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.ecommerce.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.ecommerce.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.ecommerce.app.utils.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.ecommerce.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.ecommerce.app.utils.GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.ecommerce.app.SplashscreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.ShoppingCartActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.AuthenticateActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.BranchLocationActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.ProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.VoucherActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.EShopFragmentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.EShopDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.PaypalActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.FeedbackActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.LoyaltyActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.ecommerce.app.VoucherDisplayActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.ecommerce.app.utils.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/map_key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: @Simas this is the error , i am not getting any error in logcat

Comment: `adb shell am force-stop com.my.app.package` use this in command prompt

Comment: @AnandSavjani ok i try

Comment: @AnandSavjani no progress sir..getting same error

Comment: which error you get @navya madam ?

Comment: Thanku ...for helping.....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying google play services version in `meta-data`

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

From google maps doc-https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

> Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the
>   following declaration within the  element. This embeds
>   the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with.